# Find all strings not preceeded by another, with anything in between in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, negative-lookbehind

I know using a simple negative lookbehind

```
#(?<!first word)\r\nsecond word#s
```

This will not find `second word` in

```
some text
first word
second word
some text
```

and matches as expected in

```
some text
second word
some text
```

It also matches here, but it should not

```
some text
first word
any other text
second word
some text
```

How do I need to modify my regular expression to meet the requirements ?

I tried `#(?<!first word).*second word#s`, but it always matches.

I need this to search through many files in notepad++

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Your first regex is working https://regex101.com/r/qU7nN0/3 . See , it fails to match in the third block.

Comment: @Jerry It's for notepad++, to do a search in many files in a folder.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Ok, can your requirement also be rephrased as: find the first `second word` but there should not be any `first word` from the start of the file to `second word`?

Answer (score 0):

Your first regexp is matching 3rd example as if it is looking a string that is not `first word` and which has a `second word` as a next string.

The last regexp would match everything because of `.*` which is matching everything.

I'm suggesting to add a `.*` in negative  lookbehind.

I don't know which editor you are using, so please correct if it's not corresponding to your's regexp syntax.

I would search a maximal long string which has not `first word` to be proceeded by `second word` like this

`^(?!.*first word.*)\r\nsecond word`

I hope it will work.

Good luck!

Comment: No, this regex requires to start with `\r\nsecond word`. Therefore it matches none of my cases. When I omit the `^` it does not either what it should.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Really a very interesting question... I have seen that this is for Notepad++ which I think is making the task more complex. Do you know how the mention start of file? I was not able to find something for this...if there will be a possibility to mark a start of fail then solution is obvious... Otherwise it will match only the part of file...